# How to capture hyphen, space or none and ignore case?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a Regex in C# to capture all these potential strings:

```
Test Pre-Requisite
Test PreRequisite
Test Pre Requisite
```

Of course the user could also enter any possible case. So it would be great to be able to ignore case. The best I can do is:

```
Regex TestPreReqRegex = new Regex("Test Pre[- rR]");
If (TestPreReqRegex.IsMatch(StringToCompare)){
    // Do Stuff
}
```

But this doesn't capture "Test PreRequisite" and also doesn't capture lower case. How can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `Regex TestPreReqRegex = new Regex("Test Pre[- ]?Requisite", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`. You probably want to add some boundaries though. If you're trying to match an entire string, surround your pattern with `^` and `$`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to match the entire string, use:

```
Regex TestPreReqRegex = new Regex("^Test Pre[- ]?Requisite$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you're looking for partial matches, then change the pattern to:

```
\bTest Pre[- ]?Requisite
```

Or:

```
\bTest Pre[- ]?R
```

**Pattern details:**

- `^` - Beginning of string.
- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `[- ]?` - Match a hyphen or a space character between zero and one times.
- `$` - End of string.

**C# Demo:**

```
var inputs = new[] 
    { "Test Pre-Requisite", "Test PreRequisite", "Test Pre Requisite" };
Regex TestPreReqRegex = new Regex("^Test Pre[- ]?Requisite$",
                                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (string s in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is {1}'.", s,
                      TestPreReqRegex.IsMatch(s) ? "a match" : "not a match");
}
```

**Output:**

```
'Test Pre-Requisite' is a match'.
'Test PreRequisite' is a match'.
'Test Pre Requisite' is a match'.
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/OIQ73076)**.